# Reliable ways to know the battery capacity of my iPhone 6s?

Tags: iphone, battery

I want to know the battery capacity of my iPhone 6s. What reliable ways are there ? Apps I have tried gave me — the same evening — different results : 1690 mAh, 1492 mAh, 1400 mAh.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to provide more info on what you're looking for?  Do you mean the original capacity when new, the max capacity now, the max number of hours to hold a charge, etc?

Comment: @fsb - I mean the capacity. That is the capacity now.